# KineticJS stage drag and zoom on mobile devices is very slow

Tags: kineticjs

I have problems with dragging a stage and zoom in/out on the mobile devices. Performance is very slow if i have more then 100 objects (shapes, texts, ...). On desktop drag isn't very slow, but i'm sure it could be faster.
I use 2 to 5 layers (static content, hover content, dynamic content, seats and text layer). Text and seats layer have a group of all texts / seats. Usually there are 50 to 100 text objects and 200 to 600 seat (Circle) objects.

Example is available on our production web kiosk:
http://www.mojekarte.si/en/basket/add/84766
Then choose '2. BALKON'.

*If you are testing this on touch device, then click on the 'Switch to venue map selection'.*

I was testing on Android 4.1.2 default web browser and Chrome 33.

**Stage drag**

I tried to use .cache on the stage and layer before drag. But it didn't revert me the events on the shapes after the drag has ended.
This is my stage configuration:

```
this.container = 'abc';
this.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container : this.container,
  width : 750,
  height : 500,
  draggable : true
});
```

**Stage zoom**

Zoom events were copied from http://jsfiddle.net/45YJH/1/ with little modifications

```
this.zoomFactor = 0.3;
this.zoomOrigin = makePos(0, 0);
this.pinchLastDist = 0;
this.pinchStartCenter = 0;
if (true == this.isTouch) {
    // this is mobile device and add touch events for zoom
    this.stage.getContent().addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent iPAD panning
        var touch1 = e.touches[0];
        var touch2 = e.touches[1];
        if (touch1 && touch2) {
            touch1.offsetX = touch1.clientX;;
            touch1.offsetY = touch1.clientY;
            touch2.offsetX = touch2.clientX;;
            touch2.offsetY = touch2.clientY;
            stage[this.idItem].stagePinch.call(self, makePos(touch1.offsetX, touch1.offsetY), makePos(touch2.offsetX, touch2.offsetY), this.idItem);
        }
    }.bind(this), false);

    this.stage.getContent().addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
        stage[this.idItem].pinchLastDist = stage[this.idItem].pinchStartCenter = 0;
        fixDrawing();
    }.bind(this), false);
} else {
     // IE, Opera, Safari
    $(this.stage.content).on(
        'mousewheel',
        {idItem: this.idItem},
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var evt = e.originalEvent;
            stage[idItem].stageMouseWheel.call(self, evt.wheelDelta , makePos(evt.clientX, evt.clientY), idItem);
        }
    );
    // Firefox
    $(this.stage.content).on(
        'DOMMouseScroll',
        {idItem: this.idItem},
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var evt = e.originalEvent;
            stage[idItem].stageMouseWheel.call(self, -1 * evt.detail, makePos(evt.clientX, evt.clientY), idItem);
        }
    );
}
```

fixDrawing is to fix the bug on the Android default browser (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35474#c41)

**Auto resize**

I've added resize listener on the window, to redraw the canvas if screen size has changed. I double checked and this function is triggered only on init to set canvas size.

---

Do you have any idea how to solve the slow performance issue on mobile devices?
I can provide you more source code for debugging the issue.

---

**Update**
I've tried to cache the stage with:

```
this.stage.on('dragstart', function() { this.cache(); });  
this.stage.on('dragend', function() { this.clearCache(); });
```

but the KineticJS throws exception - kinetic-v5.0.1.js (line 2255)
TypeError: context is null - context.save();

Comment: Best way - is using `cache` or `toImage`. You may cache stage before dragging, then hide all elements except cached image, then drag only one image.

Comment: I've updated my question with cache. But i get the exception - i have to click few times on the stage to revert the mouseOver, mouseDown events on the segments.